# RHEL 7.4 adding permanent static route error

Tags: redhat, static-routes

I need to add a static route to my system.
I can do it with no problem at the command line with:

```
ip route add 10.126.2.0/23 via 10.126.1.5 src 10.2.14.205
```

To make it permanent I created the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-tun10` 
file with the following line:

```
10.126.2.0/23 via 10.126.1.5 src 10.2.14.205
```

But when I run `ifup tun10` command (even after a `ifdown tun10` command) I get the following error:

```
".ror: inet address is expected rather than "10.2.14.205
```

Could somebody, please, help me understand and solve the problem?

Thanks.
Paolo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `route-tun10` file has a stray carriage return at the end of the line. This is usually because the file was created on Windows and then copied to the system. It's a good idea to avoid Windows text editors due to their line endings causing confusion on Linux systems, unless you can explicitly configure the text editor to use Unix line endings.

To fix the problem with this file, run `dos2unix` on it, which will remove the carriage returns and leave only newlines. For example:

```
sudo dos2unix /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-tun10
```